# How to add additional variable headers to .txt file?

Tags: python, header

So I am trying to add headers to data in .txt

With the current code I have it creates headers; however, it also deletes the values correlated for each variable.

Any suggestions on how I can create a code that does not delete my values?

```
infile=open("Z:\\data2.txt", "r")
outfile =open("Z:\\data3.txt", "w")

count=0
for line in infile.readlines():
    if count<1:
        d="concord_Old_SAT_V"
        e="concord_Old_SAT_M"
        f="concord_Old_SAT_W"
        g="concord_ACT_C"
        h="concord_ACT_R"
        i="concord_New_SAT_C"
        j="concord_New_SAT_RW"
        k="concord_New_SAT_M"
        l="concord_New_SAT_R_Test"
        m="concord_New_SAT_W_Test"
        n="concord_New_SAT_M_Test"
    outfile.write(line.strip("\n") + '\t' + d + '\t'+ e + '\t' + f + '\t' + g + '\t' + h + '\t' + i + '\t' + j+ '\t' + k + '\t' + l+ '\t' + m + '\t' + n+ "\n")
    count+=1
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a look to the csv module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html Looks like it can do the work for you **:-)**

Comment: We have no idea how you opened the file, so it may be hard to tell whether you are appending or just outright writing. Show how you opened the file.

Comment: That code has indentation errors.  Fix them, so we can tell what you're actually running.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! fixed the indentation errors

Comment: Why don't you just write the header line _before_ you start copying the data lines? But as others have said, take a look at the csv module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your header-less data are contained in `Z:\\data2.txt`, then all you have to do is open the file in `r+` mode, read the content and put it back after prepending your headers to the content. You may not need to make a file at all. The following should be a decent starting point:

```
headers = ["concord_Old_SAT_V",
  "concord_Old_SAT_M",
  "concord_Old_SAT_W",
  "concord_ACT_C",
  "concord_ACT_R",
  "concord_New_SAT_C",
  "concord_New_SAT_RW",
  "concord_New_SAT_M",
  "concord_New_SAT_R_Test",
  "concord_New_SAT_W_Test",
  "concord_New_SAT_M_Test"]

with open('Z:\\data2.txt','r+') as infile:
  content = infile.read()
  infile.seek(0,0)
  infile.write("\t".join(headers)+"\n"+content)
```

I hope this helps.